# How to save an item the user selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My app starts with five cells (Ca, Alk, Mg, PO3, NO3). When the user taps on the cell they want to dose lets say Ca, it segues to a screen that have all of the Ca products. From there they get to pick which Ca product they need to use, which segues to the calculator screen where they can calculate the dosage they need.

I need to find a way for the user to save the product they chose, so lets say they selected Ca, I want them to save the product in the Ca list, if they chose Alk, I want them to save the product in the Alk list.

I am lost here whether UserDefaults is okay for this or if I need CoreData.

Comment: What exactly is the 'product' that you want to save? Is it just a String value or is it your own custom type?

Comment: The product is my own custom type, here is how it looks `ProductName(name: "Aquaforest KH Plus", productType: ReefDoser.ProductComposition.liquid, productRatio: 0.660268, productCategory: ReefDoser.ProductType.alkalinity)`

Comment: You "could" save it in User Defaults, but you shouldn't!   I'd implement some kind of a database to store such data.   CoreData, Realm, Firebase, sqlite, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would use CoreData over UserDefaults for this. CoreData is designed to solve persistence in a more general way that will scale with the needs of what you are building. It's possible to do what you describe with either one - but the modeling of your data, with generated files will provide your code with safety, migrations, and performance if you use core data.

[See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407594/when-should-i-use-the-various-storage-mechanisms-in-ios) for determining which data storage types to use based on the problem you are trying to solve.

For help in how to actually use CoreData - this article gives some code examples for basic CRUD operations.

[Basic CoreData Tutorial](https://medium.com/@ankurvekariya/core-data-crud-with-swift-4-2-for-beginners-40efe4e7d1cc)