# AppStorage vs CoreData

Tags: swiftui, ios14

Recent newbie to SwiftUI and was noticed the introduction of property wrapper `@AppStorage` in iOS 14.
Wondering about the difference between `@AppStorage` and `CoreData`

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @AppStorage("isDarkMode") 
  private var isDarkMode: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(isDarkMode ? "Dark" : "Light")

      Toggle(isOn: $isDarkMode) {
        Text("Switch Mode")
      }.fixedSize()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: AppStorage is just a convenient observable wrapper around UserDefaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AppStorage` is a property-wrapper around `UserDefaults` for `SwiftUI`. So whatever you're storing using `AppStorage` is available also via `UserDefaults`.

```
@AppStorage("isDarkMode") private var isDarkMode: Bool = false
//...
let isDarkMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode")
```

`CoreData` is where you store large amounts of data. You can go through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16408993/7098650).